# How to use one object value in different classes in java

Tags: java

Hi I will be generating a Random number

```
Random randomno = new Random();
int random = randomno.nextInt(10000);
```

I want use this random number value in different class. If I create the Object of this class, every time this values changes. But for one execution I want to maintain one value throughout the application.

Comment: I suggest you store it in a field of the object.

Comment: Even better a `final` field

Comment: Paolo has a point, but also you could think of adding this into a method and not a class.... it would be more functional...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a re-usable method to generate a random number, you could create a special class that does that for you:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumberGenerator {

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();


    private RandomNumberGenerator() {

    }

    //Usage: RandomNumberGenerator.getRandomNumber(10000);
    public static int getRandomNumber(int max) {
        return RANDOM.nextInt(max);
    }
}
```

This can in turn be used in another class and results can be saved to an arraylist or whatever you like. Example demo:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Integer> randomNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            randomNumbers.add(RandomNumberGenerator.getRandomNumber(10000));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Random number generated from RandomNumberGenerator can be used anywhere and these random will get stored in Main class ?

Comment: That depends on where you save them: if you wanted to you could declare a `static List<Integer>` in the RandomNumberGenerator class and store them in there, so the random numbers are maintained throughout the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible way:**

1) Add your code in application class, and there make one field as static, any anywhere you want this field you can use it. **(recommended)**

2) Store data in shared pred or db.

3) make a singleton pattern which is answer given by nbokmans user.